# Make RestTemplate process response body regardless of status

Tags: java, facebook, spring, facebook-graph-api, resttemplate

I'm using Spring MVC, and I'm trying to experiment with the Facebook API, just for fun.
The problem I'm having currently, is that Facebook's GRAPH Api returns other status codes than 200 when it encounters an `OAuthException`. However, the body of the response is still a valid json object, and I would like to parse it into my object.

This way, my `restTemplate` will invoke the errorhandler, when the status code is anything else than HTTP.2xx, and not parse the response to my object.

Is there any way of configuring the RestTemplate so that it should parse the response body regardless of http status?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set a customer `ResponseErrorHandler`

```
restTemplate.setErrorHandler(customerErrorHandler)
```

you'll just need to implement the following two methods

```
boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException;
void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException;
```

in your case `hasError`could always return `false`

Comment: I have tried this approach, but the response still has status other than 200, making tomcat return an error page instead of the object. Any way to modify the response code in the errorhandler?

Comment: Welp, it was basically my own mistake. It works now, and this is somewhat of a solution :) Marking as resolved.